# Superclass property not initialized in Derived class

Tags: inheritance, kotlin

I have the following Kotlin Code:

```
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.HashSet

open class Graph(open val n: Int) {
    val graph = List<MutableSet<Int>>(n) {HashSet<Int>()}

    open fun addEdge(u: Int, v: Int) {
        graph[u].add(v)
        graph[v].add(u)
    }

    val numEdges: Int
        get() {
            return graph.asSequence()
                    .map { it.size }
                    .reduce { x, y -> x + y }
        }   

    fun edgeSet() : HashSet<Pair<Int,Int>> {
        val result = HashSet<Pair<Int,Int>>()
        for (i in graph.indices) {
            for(j in graph[i]) {
                if(i<j) result.add(i to j)
                else result.add(j to i)
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Graph(n=$n, graph=$graph)"
    }
}

class DGraph(override val n: Int) : Graph(n) {
    override fun addEdge(u: Int, v: Int) {
        graph[u].add(v)
    }
}
```

However, when i create an instance of DGraph, and use it in the following code:

```
val graph = DGraph(5)
println(graph.graph.size)
graph.addEdge(0,1)
```

I find that the graph property is not initialized in the DGraph instance, and I get and IndexOutOfBoundsException. Why does this happen?

Comment: If the `graph` property were not initialised, then the `graph.graph.size` would fail.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, Yes, I know that. But why is the graph property not being initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Remove `override val` from the `DGraph` constructor param.

Your code is secretly equivalent to the following Java pseudo-code:

```
class Graph {
    private final int n;
    private final List<MutableSet<Int>> graph;

    Graph(int n) {
        this.n = n;
        this.graph = someStuffThatCreatesAList(getN());
    }

    int getN() { return n; }

    // ...
}

class DGraph extends Graph {
    private final int n;

    DGraph(int n) {
        super(n);
        this.n = n;
    }

    int getN() { return n; }

    // ...
}
```

So during the `Graph` constructor, the overriden `getN` gets called.  However, the sub-class members have not been initialised yet, so it returns the default value (`0`).

By removing `override val`, you eliminate the override to `getN`.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I did try removing override only to get an error. I never thought of removing val as I needed n as a property in DGraph too. Now I understand it all better.